# rails parsing ill-identified parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following response is being received

```
   Parameters: {"anBfcmV0dXJuX2hhc2g9OTY1MGU3MmFm[truncated]UJkVORD1FTkQ"=>"", "id"=>"result_url"}
```

as the result of a call to an external system.  The result is a string that need to be decoded via Base64.

However, Rails interprets this result as a parameter key with a blank value.

How can this very long key string be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most beautiful solution, just a workaround:

```rb
params.keys.select {|param| param != 'id'}.first
```

But it would become so ugly if you'll have more params

Comment: agreed it would be messy.  But this is exactly the practical case, so it fits.

Comment: glad it helped :)